# Warning: failed prop type: Required prop 'region.latitude' was not specified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem but I don't know if it's linked to this.

When I'm running my map on Android Emulator from Android Studio, I have this warning and I'm geolocate on Google plex on Palo alto and not on my actual geolocation. Is it because I use an emulator or not ?

Here is my code if you want to check :

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Geolocation from '../geolocation/Geolocation';
import Shops from '../shops/Shop';
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import styles from './Style';

class Map extends Geolocation {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: this.state.position.coords.latitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.001,
          longitude: this.state.position.coords.longitude,
          longitudeDelta: 0.001
        }} />
        <Shops />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Geolocation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Style';

class Geolocation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            position : {
                coords: {}
            }
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({position});
            },
            (error) => alert(error.message),
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000}
        );
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
            this.setState({position});
        });
    }
}

export default Geolocation;
```

Thanks for your answer if you have any ideas, I am a little bit lost with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you're assigning out the `MapView` coordinates from `this.state.position.cords` object, which on initial render will be undefined for `cords.latitude` and `cords.longitude`, thus throwing the `propTypes` warning.

Initialize them in the constructor to avoid this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        position : {
            coords: {
              latitude: 0,
              longitude: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem in only Android**

**Solution :-**

```js
<MapView 
  initialRegion={{
    latitude: Number(letitude),
    longitude: Number(longitude),
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  }}
>
```

***Number(your let and long)*** it will convert in number

Answer (score 1):

```
initialRegion={{
   longitude: origin ? origin.longitude : 0,
   latitude: origin ? origin.latitude : 0,
}}
```

Just set it to 0 when not available

Answer (score 0):

The latitude and longitude can be changed.

Launch **Android Device Monitor** from Android Studio (Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor)

Switch to the **Emulator Control Tab** and change it in **Location Controls** group.
[image]